# How to pass value to puppeteer program that is waiting for value from an API

Tags: api, puppeteer, wait, readline

Hi I am running a puppeteer script which will pre fill the form values and will wait for the value from the command line. Once it receives the value it will enter the value in an input type and submit the form.

I am able to do it using readline(). The problem I'm facing is my script will be waiting for the value which will be provided by an API.

I need to know how to receive value from the API so that my script will use the value to fill the form and continue.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const readline = require('readline');
async function readLine() {

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        rl.question('Enter username: ', (answer) => {
            rl.close();
            resolve(answer)
        });
    });
 (async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            devtools: false,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            args: [
                '--start-fullscreen',
                '--window-size=1920,1040',
                '--no-sandbox'
            ]
        });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

        // Set windows height en width
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1600,
            height: 900
        });
   await page.goto("www.domain.com/admin");
   const userName = await readLine();
   await page.focus('#username');
   await page.keyboard.type(userName, {delay: 100});       

 })
```

This is my code.
My script will be waiting for the value. I need to pass the value to my script. which I will receive from another application. I need to know how to pass the value to my script using an API

Answer (score 0):

I faced on similar problem.

This works for me:

```js
...
const input = await page.$('#id');
await input.evaluate(
(inp, { username })=>{
    inp.value = username;
},
{ username: username } // pass params from async function here
)
```